# Use functions and parameters stored in list-cols - Purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 18 × 6
      id                     columnFilter  modelName  model               train.X        train.Y
   <int>                            <chr>      <chr> <list>                <list>         <list>
1      1              groupedColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
2      2       groupedSquaredColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
3      3   groupedTransformedColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
4      4            ungroupedColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
5      5     ungroupedSquaredColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
6      6 ungroupedTransformedColumns.donr boostModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
7      7              groupedColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
8      8       groupedSquaredColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
9      9   groupedTransformedColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
10    10            ungroupedColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
11    11     ungroupedSquaredColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
12    12 ungroupedTransformedColumns.donr   ldaModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
13    13              groupedColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
14    14       groupedSquaredColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
15    15   groupedTransformedColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
16    16            ungroupedColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
17    17     ungroupedSquaredColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 28]> <fctr [3,984]>
18    18 ungroupedTransformedColumns.donr logitModel  <fun> <tibble [3,984 × 17]> <fctr [3,984]>
```

As you can see, `modelName` is the name of the model, stored as a function in `model`.

What I want to do is for each row, call the function stored in `model`, pass it `train.X` and `train.Y` as parameters, and store the function's output into a new column.

Conceptually, something like:

```
df %>% mutate(result = pmap(train.X,train.Y,model)
```

I've been trying to use `pmap()`, but to no success.

Need some guidance here.

Comment: FYI: Each function in 'model' accepts exactly two parameters.

Comment: Try using `invoke_map` instead. I also think that a simple `apply` should do this: `df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x$model(x$train.X, x$train.Y))` should go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke_map` should work after you combine `train.X` and `train.Y` into a list. Here's a basic example in a similar situation that could be tested. `tib` mimics your situation in that `x` and `y` are parameters you need to provide the function. In the example, I use the `runif` function which takes the parameters plus `n`. I use `map2` to get `x` and `y` wrapped in a list column called "params". Then I use the `invoke_map()` function to iteratively apply functions to the params.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Basic example
tib <- tribble(
    ~fun, ~x, ~y,
    runif, -1, 1,
    runif, -10, 10,
    runif, -3,3
)
tib
#> # A tibble: 3 Ã— 3
#>      fun     x     y
#>   <list> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  <fun>    -1     1
#> 2  <fun>   -10    10
#> 3  <fun>    -3     3

tib %>%
    mutate(params = map2(x, y, list)) %>%
    mutate(result = invoke_map(fun, params, n = 5))
#> # A tibble: 3 Ã— 5
#>      fun     x     y     params    result
#>   <list> <dbl> <dbl>     <list>    <list>
#> 1  <fun>    -1     1 <list [2]> <dbl [5]>
#> 2  <fun>   -10    10 <list [2]> <dbl [5]>
#> 3  <fun>    -3     3 <list [2]> <dbl [5]>
```

Now we just need to apply the same procedure to your example. This should work.

```r
df %>%
    mutate(params = map2(train.X, train.Y, list)) %>%
    mutate(result = invoke_map(model, params))
```

Comment: Matt, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Your example works if ONE model() is defined externally. What I need is to use the model-functions embedded within the dataframe (column #4). For each row, the function is different, so I need some way to map the three together (For each row in df$model, pass it df$train.X, and df$train.Y)

Comment: Yep, I see that now. I was confused by the use of `pmap` because typically it's a function that is outside of the data frame. When it's inside, you need to use `invoke_map`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Matt!