# Reactive tibble columns

Tags: r, reactive-programming, tibble

Is it possible to create reactive tibble columns in the sense that the values of column `y` are **actively** linked to column `x`? So that whenever `x` changes, `y` changes accordingly based on a defined mutation logic. Think "MS Excel spreadsheets".

I guess it eventually boils down to being able to put functions (containing what would go into a `dplyr::mutate` statement) in columns and "have them be called automatically" whenever the tibble or the actual column is used/accessed/printed/etc.

AFAIU `tibble::tibble()` doesn't support this (see shiny example below: when using `y` instead of `y()` at the end of the mutate statement, you would get the error "Column `y` is of unsupported type function").

One could probably come up with a design using `purrr` functionality (wrapping functions in lists and using `purrr:map2` and/or `purrr:invoke_map`, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604498/use-functions-and-parameters-stored-in-list-cols-purrr)), but I'm looking for a "simpler" solution if possible.

This is what I tried so far:

```
# Packages -----
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(shiny)
```

### Base R: makeActiveBinding

```
tb <- tibble(x = c(1, 2))
tb_2 <- tb %>% mutate(y = {
  makeActiveBinding("y", local(function() x * 10), environment())
  y
})
tb_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    10
#> 2     2    20
tb_2$x <- c(10, 20)
tb_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    10
#> 2    20    20
```

After updating column `x`, I'd like column `y` values to be `100` and `200`.

### Shiny: makeReactiveBinding

```
options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)

tb <- tibble(x = c(1, 2))
tb_2 <- tb %>% mutate(y = {
  .x <- .$x
  makeReactiveBinding(".x")
  y <- reactive(.x * 10, environment())
  y()
})
tb_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    10
#> 2     2    20
tb_2$x <- c(10, 20)
tb_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    10
#> 2    20    20
```

Comment: Are you planning to use this in a shiny context? Or is this for some non-web based analysis? The solution in most things in R is to wrap a function around the functionality you need. Rather than relying on mysterious triggered events and side effects, just explicitly call a function when you need values to be updated.

Comment: @MrFlick good point, should've mentioned that. It would be for a non-shiny context, I just like experimenting on using reactive paradigms in general.

Comment: @MrFlick I would indeed like to stick to using actual functions if possible to make/keep mutation logic explicit. But ideally I wouldn't have to repeat all of my `dplyr::mutate` calls **explicitly** every time some fundamental values change but have that automated in some low-level way

Comment: Why not just make an intermediary function that applies a known change to your desired object. In your case, pass in the second tibble along and a vector of numbers to multiply, and it returns your modified tibble. Reactive programming makes sense in a web-based context; I don’t really see its use in an R console.

Comment: Shiny pulls off reactive programming but creating a context where there is an event loop where objects can respond to events. There's not really such a thing in base R. Perhaps you could create your own object type that tracks state each time a property is requested, but that's not going to happen with a tibble. If this is purely about making R reactive, I can't help you there. But if this about solving a messy code problem, I wish you could go into more specifics about your exact problem in the question.

Comment: @Cybernetic sure, that would of course work. As I said, this is rather an thought/code experiment. But I do see use cases where this might make sense apart from the classical "shiny web-app" context. For example, at work we're using a custom developed client-server architecture for communicating between our flagship software and R. It's designed in a RESTful manner, but whenever state would matter, something that is reactive on a low level might actually be quite nice.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for taking the time, but it's really merely an experiment for the mere fun of it. I did play around with understanding reactivity back in 2014 ([blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900626/reactive-object-bindings-in-a-non-shiny-context) which lead to [reactr](https://github.com/rappster/reactr)) and wondered if this could be leveraged somehow "to the tidyverse" - thus the explicit goal of using a `tibble` instead of defining custom `R6` objects or something along those lines.